# Why is it faster in Google Sheets to split this formula into two steps?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, count, sequence, spreadsheet

**Edit: I initially diagnosed this problem totally wrong, so the question is entirely rewritten to reflect new understanding.**

The problem can be reproduced using a Google spreadsheet with one sheet that contains one header row and a significant number of additional rows (let’s say 5,000).

I wanted column A to increment by 1, starting with `A2`, as long as the adjacent cell in B was not blank. I used this formula in `A1`:

```
={"SKU"; arrayformula(if($B2:$B="","",text(row($A2:$A),"000000")))}
```

This formula worked but caused extremely significant lag.

In one of my attempts to resolve the issue, I added a helper column before column A and split my formula into two formulas to see which function was causing the lag:

Cell A1: `={"SKU (helper)"; arrayformula(if($C2:$C="","",row($A2:$A)))}`

Cell B1: `={"SKU"; arrayformula(if($C2:$C="","",text($A2:$A,"000000")))}`

To my surprise, the answer was neither. The lag was completely eliminated. What is the reason? And is it possible to eliminate the lag without the need for a helper column?

Comment: Is the lag still present with your original formula?

Comment: The significant lag persists with the original formula, which can be witnessed when reordering rows (among other actions). The green progress bar in the top right just crawls. The lag goes away completely only when I split the formula into the two columns. I didn't want two columns, but this is my solution for now because the lag is pretty extreme otherwise.

Comment: I just copied the values of my sheet to another sheet and the lag also went away even when using just the one formula. I don’t know. Perhaps it was some kind of corruption on the sheet itself. Sorry, I didn’t expect such a thing. I’ll know to try that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
={"SKU"; SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A)-5344; 1; 5344)}
```

---

### update:

```
={"SKU"; INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B)), "000000"))}
```

[image]

if you have empty cells in between use:

```
=LAMBDA(x, {"SKU"; INDEX(IF(x="",,
 TEXT(COUNTIFS(x, "<>", ROW(x), "<="&ROW(x)), "000000")))})
 (B2:INDEX(B:B, MAX((B:B<>"")*ROW(B:B))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I kept sitting with the problem, trying to debug it, and ultimately found the issue was different from how I initially understood. I rewrote the question and also the workaround solution I found. But there's still the question of why Google Sheets behaves this way.

Comment: This whole problem has been a mess to figure out. I think the lag was unique to my sheet as it could not be reproduced on another sheet with the same values pasted. Anyway, thanks again. I like your answer that allows blanks!